# WinForm Controls are transparent, and not displaying properly

Tags: c#, winforms

When a form loads, I'd like it to show a loading image (within a Picture Box) and a standard Windows label with some text. However, all I see are white boxes, or sometimes I see another form underneath. How do I get the image and label to display properly.

I've tried setting `AllowTransparency` to `false` when the form loads, and also setting the Transparency Key of the form to some other colour, but nothing has worked.

The project is C# .Net v3.5 (also tried v4 and v4.5).

Any ideas?

Comment: A GUI can do only one thing at a time.  When it "loads a form" it cannot also keep the GUI updated.  Call the form's Update() method explicitly so it is at least fully painted.  Get ahead by running expensive code, like dbase queries, on a worker thread or by using async/await.

Comment: I couldn't find an Update method in the form. I've had a quick look at threading but from the examples I found it wouldn't let me amend the form label from within the thread.

Comment: The Form class has an Update() method.  Inherited from the Control class.  Best to leave it up to the compiler to find it, otherwise no idea what "I couldn't find it" might mean.  It is an instance method, in case that matters.

Comment: When I said I couldn't find it, it's not in the Properties window for the form, and not in Intellisense either.

Comment: It's just been an absolutely awful day for "it doesn't work" questions.  Pulling the tooth one more time: what *do* you see in the IntelliSense dropdown?  And more productively, what does your code actually look like?  Please don't make us guess at it.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can't display an image, busy-wait, and then change the image - this will never redraw anything, leading to the symptoms you describe. To "wait" you will need to return control to your main application loop so it can continue to process messages (e.g. to handle redraw requests for your window). One way to do what you want is to display your initial state (splash screen) and then use a timer to call you back later to change the display to your second state.

The next problem you face is using forms controls with transparency. Most controls treat "transparent" as "fill your background with your parent controls color", which is not what you want. An easy way around this is to implement a Paint handler and draw the image and text for yourself - this gives you much more control of how your display looks, and will also allow you to get a cleaner redraw (no flicker or other problems caused by the display being built up but by bit in several controls)

Lastly, consider implementing your splash screen display as a separate control/form that you show above your main form during loading, as that makes it easy to "overlay" on your main form without having to change its design at all.

Comment: The transparency is just an artifact, a good way to get transparency is to not paint :)

Comment: I'm not looking to change the image - I want it to display the image instead of a white box. If I remove the image so there's just the label, it doesn't display that either!

Answer (score -1):

Just write `formObjectName.Refresh()` after `formObjectName.Show()`